# Can somebody post some code example of how to http authenticate from iphone objective c using xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Can somebody post some code example(code or link) of how to http authenticate from iphone objective c using xcode?

I wanna to go to my web application passing through POST login and passord and be able to return the response to validate it is authenticated or not

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're doing form-based authentication, passing credentials as POST variables. If you already have a third-party networking wrapper you're using (such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)), read its documentation to find out what facilities it has for sending POST variables.

If you want to roll your own, the basic process is:

- Create an [`NSMutableURLRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with the login URL
- Use the `setHTTPMethod:` method to set the request's method to "POST"
- Escape and concatenate your credentials to construct a [well-formed POST body](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29)
- Set the POST body of the request object with `setHTTPBody:`
- Send the request with an [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and receive the response using its synchronous or asynchronous API.

Answer (score 0):

> Can somebody post some code example(code or link) of how to http authenticate from iphone objective c using Xcode?

See the [Advanced URL Connections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/) sample project Apple provides in the iOS developer centre.

> I wanna to go to my web application passing through POST login and passord and be able to return the response to validate it is authenticated or not

That's not HTTP authentication.  That's just a normal HTTP POST.